# Operaciones matemáticas

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2015, tengo la necesidad de hacer esta operación matemática pero no estoy usando variables.

```
decimal porciento = ((18 + 100) / 100);
```

¿Como debo hacerlo?, asi como esta me da como respuesta `1` y debe salir `1.18`

Comment: Por favor, evita duplicar preguntas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias intentar usando

```
decimal porciento = ((decimal)(18 + 100) / 100);
```

al definir el tipo de datos de la operacion suma, .net infiere el tipo para el resto de la operacion

Comment: Gracias, Leandro no se me habia ocurrido castear

Comment: Tambien indicar que por ejemplar, se infiere el tipo si pones 18.0 en vez de 18. Otra alternativa es multiplicar la suma por 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando divides dos números del tipo entero, el resultado siempre se truncará al número entero anterior más cercano. En tu ejemplo eso ocurre porque en C# se asume que 118 / 100 son números enteros a pesar de asignar el resultado a una variable del tipo decimal o de cualquier otro tipo.

Para corregir esto, puedes convertir uno de los operandos (o ambos) al tipo decimal mediante un casting tal como sugirió Leandro en el otro comentario, porque al realizar una operación entre un número entero y uno decimal, el compilador convertirá el número entero a decimal, para que así la operación sea entre decimales y dará como resultado un número del tipo decimal. Claro que esta conversión provoca cierta sobrecarga, aunque una muy pequeña, pero imagina tener que realizar miles de operaciones con sus correspondientes conversiones. Para no tener que hacer casting alguno, puedes indicarle al compilador que tus literales son del tipo decimal y no entero añadiendo como subfijo la letra `m`

```
decimal porciento = (18M + 100M) / 100M);
```

Al realizar esto, el compilador nota que no es una operación entre enteros, sino entre decimales, cuyo resultado será del tipo decimal y así te ahorras el proceso de realizar la conversión (o que el compilador lo haga por ti).

Algo parecido se puede realizar con literales del tipo float, double, long, uint y ulong:

- Para los tipos float, se añade el prefijo `f` luego del literal numérico para ser reconocido como tal y no como entero (o doble, en caso de llevar decimales, ya que el compilador asume que cualquier literal con cifras decimales es del tipo double). Ej.: `var flotante = 5F / 4F;`, lo que resultaría directamente en 1.25.
- Para los tipos doubles, en caso de querer realizar una operación entre dos números enteros (enteros en el sentido matemático), se utiliza el subfijo `d` o,  como alternativa, habría que simplemente añadir `.0`como subfijo. Ej: `5.0 / 4.0`, tal como se mencionó antes, el compilador asume que todo número con decimal es del tipo double.
- Para los tipo long, uint y ulong, de forma parecida, se añade el subfijo `l, u, ul` respectivamente y será reconocido como tal y no como entero.

[Referencia](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Jorge, muy interesante.