# Cómo truncar decimales y no redondear a una cifra significativa

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2015, estoy haciendo una operación matemática en la cual uso decimales, en el cual solo obtengo un número con dos decimales pero no deseo que lo redondee.

```
_subTotal = ( _total/((decimal)(18+100)/100));
```

Al hacer la siguiente operación 650/1.18 = 550.8474576271186 al tomar el resultado en un label lo hago de la siguiente manera `lblSubTotal.Text = _subTotal.ToString("N2");` pero el resultado que obtengo es `550.85` pero no deseo que lo redondee solo necesito `550.84`, ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Operaciones matemáticas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20657/operaciones-matem%c3%a1ticas)

Comment: @Mauricio Son preguntas distintas con respuestas distintas. En la [primera](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20657/127) se explica cómo mantener los tipos en una operación. En esta pregunta, cómo truncar decimales.

Comment: @Mauricio son preguntas distintas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Está bien que lo redondee y corresponde desde lo aritmético.

Para **truncar** la parte decimal de un número se usa [Math.Truncate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/7d101hyf(v=vs.110).aspx).

```cs
Math.Truncate(550.847457)                 //=> 550
Math.Truncate(550.847457 * 100) / 100     //=> 550.84
Math.Truncate(550.847457 * 1000) / 1000   //=> 550.847
Math.Truncate(550.847457 * 10000) / 10000 //=> 550.8474
```

---

Para tu ejemplo en particular

```cs
decimal _total = 650;
decimal _subTotal = Math.Truncate(_total * 10000 /(100+18)) / 100;

string resultado =  _subTotal.ToString("N2");
```

Resultado: `550.84`

<kbd>[Demo en ideone](http://ideone.com/qsBR6v)</kbd>

Comment: Gracias, @Mariano

Comment: ¿porque por 10000? sera por que para hacer el calculo me toma cuatro decimales y lo divides entre 100 para que me de como resultado dos decimales.

Answer (score 0):

Método para truncar los decimales de cualquier número la cantidad de decimales deseados. Se puede cambiar el tipo de dato

```
public static double round(this double d, byte p) 
{ 
    return Math.Truncate(d * Math.Pow(10, p)) / Math.Pow(10, p); 
}
```